# WebStorm switcher shortcuts on MacOS don't work

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm running WebStorm on Mac OS and for some weird reason, I can't get the 'switcher' shortcuts to properly work.

When I click `Ctrl` + `Tab` I get the 'switcher' window, then I want to be able to keep the `Ctrl` key pressed, and navigate between the open files with the arrow keys. This doesn't work at all.

I changed the keyboard shortcut in the KeyMaps area in the settings, and saved it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so do not trust me much .. but those `Ctrl+Arrow` keys could be handled at OS-wide level (desktop related actions I believe) -- so check there first. EDIT: like http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18043 for example.

Comment: I already disabled them on my mac, because of this. I got these shortcuts to work on intelliJ, but recently I've been doing only frontend work, so I switched to using WebStorm, and I can't get it to work there! Very frustrating!! :/